# Identity for an integrable function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega \subset R^n$ ($n\geq 2$) a bounded domain. Let $u \in L^{1}(\Omega)$.
For each number $c >0$ define $A_c :=\{ x \in \Omega; u(x) > c\}$.

If $u$ is non negative I know a result that says that

$$\int_{\Omega} u dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty} |A_t| \ dt$$.

From this result it is possible to obtain the relation

$$ \int_{A_k} (u-k) dx = \int_{k}^{+\infty} |A_t| \ dt?$$

It seens that this is possible, but I have no idea of how to do it

Comment: If we define in general $A_c(f) = \{x \in \Omega\;:\;f(x) > c\}$, how is $A_t(u - k)$ related to $A_t = A_t(u)$?

Comment: I dont know anything that can help.  Do you have something um mind?

Comment: Yes. You apply the result you mention to $u-k$ instead of to $u$.

Comment: I should have asked about how $A_{t-k}(u-k)$ relates to $A_t$. I forgot to offset the subscript.

Comment: I am not seeing how to do this. Please could you write a solution? If you want,  of course :)

Answer (score 1):

$$A_{t - k}(u - k) = \{x \in \Omega\;:\; u(x) - k > t - k\} = \{x \in \Omega\;:\; u(x) > t \} = A_t$$

Or you can write it as $A_t(u - k) = A_{t + k}$.

If $c \ge d$, then $A_c(f) \subseteq A_d(f)$, so $A_c(f) = \{x \in A_d(f):\; f(x)  > c\}$. Therefore if $t >= k$, we can treat $A_k$ as the domain instead of $\Omega$.

So, applying the theorem to $u - k$ on $A_k$, we have
$$\begin{align}\int_{A_k} (u - k) \ dx &= \int_{0}^{+\infty} |A_t(u - k)|\ dt \\&= \int_{0}^{+\infty} |A_{t+k}|\ dt\\&= \int_{k}^{+\infty} |A_{s}|\ ds\end{align}$$